# Error when running Truffle Test in Terminal

Tags: solidity, truffle, remix, truffle-test

I am trying to use truffle to test my smart contracts and have written some test files. I am getting an error on the terminal trying to run the test and am unsure what the reason is.

I access my directory via terminal and then write:

- truffle compile
- truffle develop
- migrate
- deploy

So far everything runs fine. Then when I type **truffle test** it returns this error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:280:10)
    at REPLServer.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at REPLServer.onLine (repl.js:468:10)
    at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:314:12)
    at bound (domain.js:301:14)
    at ReplManager.interpret (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/repl.js:119:1)
    at Console.interpret (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/console.js:164:1)
    at Object.runInContext (vm.js:119:10)
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
```

This also happens when I try to run **truffle test** followed by the address of the directory the test file I want to use is saved in.

Does anybody know what the problem might be? 
The only solutions I found for similar problems talked about it being a Windows problem. I am using a Mac though so can't apply these solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I managed to bypass it by running truffle test outside the truffle console. I run truffle.cmd test on command line (windows).

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same error(word for word) by running the following command from the truffle console "let instance = await VonCoinContract.deployed()"
Turns out it was a truffle problem.

"Truffle's console doesn't yet support the await syntax, unfortunately. But! You don't need it for that method; just do session.connect(). Check out the public methods in the Debugger API Docs, that should help. Take note which methods are labeled async, so you know which ones return Promises.
"  from https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle-debugger/issues/72

I know not the answer to your question but may be of use to someone to got here the same way I did ;)